# Saving a numpy array with mixed data

Tags: python, numpy, io

I have a numpy array where every value is a float followed by an integer, e.g.:

```
my_array = numpy.array([0.4324321, 0, 0.9437212, 1, 0.4738721, 0, 0.49327321, 0])
```

I would like to save it like this:

```
0.4324321 0 0.9437212 1 0.4738721 0 0.49327321 0
```

But if I call:

```
numpy.savetxt('output.dat',my_array,fmt='%f %i')
```

I get an error:

```
AttributeError: fmt has wrong number of % formats.  %f %i
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `savetxt` isn't a member of the `array` type. Did you mean `numpy.savetxt` there?

Comment: By the way, it would really help if you showed what you want the expected output to look like, instead of making us guess. It's no coincidence that at least two different smart people failed to read your mind (or maybe two different smart people plus one who's only as smart as me; I'm not sure I guessed right either)…

Comment: @abarnert Thanks for your comments, I edited the post to fix both of those problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your real problem is that printing out a 1D 8-element array gives you 8 rows of 1 column (or, if you force things, 1 row of 8 columns), not 4 rows of 2 columns. So, you can only specify a single format (or, if you force things, either 1 or 8 formats).

If you want to output this in a 4x2 shape instead of 1x8, you need to reshape the array first:

```
numpy.savetxt('output.dat', my_array.reshape((4,2)), fmt='%f %i')
```

This will give you:

```
0.432432 0
0.943721 1
0.473872 0
0.493273 0
```

[The docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) are a little confusing, as they devote most of the wording to dealing with complex numbers instead of simple floats and ints, but the basic rules are the same. You specify either a single specifier, or a specifier for each column (the in-between case of specifying real and imaginary parts for each column isn't relevant).

---

If you want to write it in 1 row of 8 columns, first you need to reshape it into something with 1 row of 8 columns instead of 8 rows.

And then you need to specify 8 formats. There's no way to tell numpy "repeat these two formats four times", but that's pretty easy to do without numpy's help:

```
numpy.savetxt('output.dat', my_array.reshape((1,8)), fmt='%f %i ' * 4)
```

And that gives you:

```
0.432432 0 0.943721 1 0.473872 0 0.493273 0
```

Comment: Actually I do want the 1x8 format. Is it possible to get that?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `savetxt()` will print one row for each array entry. You can force a `2D-array` creating a new axis and then print the `(1x8)` format:

```
numpy.savetxt('output.dat', my_array[numpy.newaxis,:], fmt='%f %i'*4)
```