# How to write into a .txt file in Python?

Tags: python

I would like to write the following information into a .txt file:

```
D = 68601
w = 1500
NNZ = 205806000
docword = [[    0   170     4]
           [    0  1856     4]
           [    0   838     3]
           ...
           [68601  1982     0]
           [68601  1981     0]
           [68601     0     0]]
```

This is how the final .txt file should look like -- replace the numbers:

```
D
W
NNZ
docID wordID count
docID wordID count
docID wordID count
docID wordID count
...
docID wordID count
docID wordID count
docID wordID count
```

I have tried this:

```
datafile_path = "/path/to/docword.txt"
with open(datafile_path, 'w+') as datafile_id:
      np.savetxt(datafile_id, data, fmt=['%d','%d','%d'], newline="\n")
```

and also this:

```
with open('/path/to/docword.txt', 'ab') as outfile:
     for data_slice in data:
         np.savetxt(outfile, data_slice, fmt=['%d','%d','%d'])
```

it takes forever and doesn't do what I want, also saving it as a pickle is not what I want. I want to be able to open the text file and be able to see the same format in there, 3 lines of one column and then lines of 3 columns.

Comment: ...So what's actually generated?

Comment: Maybe not duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17558484/saving-a-numpy-array-with-mixed-data) but would definitely check that out. I think `fmt='%d %d '%d'` not `fmt=['%d', '%d', '%d']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is sample code, that writes your data to file, does this meet your expectations?

```
D = 68601
w = 1500
NNZ = 205806000
docword = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
text_file = open("Output.txt", "w")
text_file.write(str(D) + '\n')
text_file.write(str(w) + '\n')
text_file.write(str(NNZ) + '\n')
for row in docword:
    for el in row:
        text_file.write(str(el) + '\t')
    text_file.write('\n')
text_file.close()
```

Output file content:

```
68601
1500
205806000
1   2   3   
4   5   6
```

Comment: Thank you. This one did what I exactly wanted to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to use `numpy.savetxt` you can just pass a file path -- no need to open up a file.
Check out the example at the end of the [doc page](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) for the function.
You want to do the following:

```
datafile_path = "/path/to/docword.txt"
np.savetxt(datafile_path, data, fmt='%d %d %d', newline="\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

A really simple way to do so is with a for loop. Although better solutions must exist with numpy.

```
import numpy as np

mat = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
n= mat.shape[0]

file = open("file.txt", "w")

for i in range(0, n):
    line = mat[i:i+1]
    file.write(str(line).strip("[").strip("]")+"\n")

file.close()
```

Output:

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
```